# aspx: sending email

Tags: email, asp.net

I would like to know can i send an email with aspx files.

i know that in php there is a mail() command to send emails but i couldn't find the one for aspx.

Comment: Beware: see here. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use [System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx) to send mail. Note that you need to have an SMTP server available.

Comment: i get the following error:   Compiler Error Message: BC30112: 'System.Net.Mail' is a namespace and cannot be used as an expression.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. System.Net.Mail is a namespace, and if you follow the link to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx, you can read about how to use the classes provided for you in that namespace to send mail from ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Use system.net.mail and define your smtp server and port in the web.config for added security